# Multinomial and Poisson relationship in contingency tables

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multinomial-distribution, contingency-tables

I am researching the relationship between multinomial and Poisson distribution in contingency tables. Is what I have said below right? For context, the multinomial pmf is below.

$$P(X_1=x_1,...,X_N=x_N)=\frac{N!}{x_1!...x_k!}p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}...p_k^{x_k}$$

On most occasions, cell counts in contingency tables have multinomial distributions, however with an appropriate interpretation of the parameters, the multinomial maximum likelihood (ML) estimates can be obtained as if we were to model the counts as Poisson random variables. Suppose that there are $X_1,..., X_k$ Poisson random variables with means $\lambda_1,..., \lambda_k$ respectively and probability $p_i$ of occurring $x_i$ times. Then $P(X_1,...,X_k \mid N)$ has the multinomial distribution. As $\sum_i^kp_i=1$, the unconditional distribution of $X_1,...X_k$ can be factored into the product of two distributions. The first is the Poisson distribution, denoted $Po$ for the total of number of observations $$N \sim Po\left(\sum_i^k \lambda_i\right)$$ The second is the multinomial distribution for $X_1,...,X_k$. This means that the likelihood function factors into two equations: one for $\sum_i^k\lambda_i$ and the other for the vector of probabilities $\boldsymbol{p}$. The total number of observations $N$ does not hold information about $\boldsymbol{p}$ and $\boldsymbol{p}$ does not hold information about $N$. Therefore, likelihood-based inferences about $\boldsymbol{p}$ are the same whether we regard $X_1,..., X_k$ as sampled from $k$ independent Poisson distributions or from a single multinomial distribution. This has shown that we are able to interpret the ML estimates of all contingency tables as if the random variables were Poisson. Therefore, throughout the rest of this report, we will let all discrete variables which are shown as a contingency table as Poisson random variables.